# how to know face contain another face with ruby api in sketchup

Tags: sketchup

I have a faceA, a faceB, faceC, faceA contains faceB, I want to know how to have Ruby API to get faceA contains faceB. but not contain faceC

```rb
faceA.all_connected.grep(Sketchup::Face)
```

this can find faceB, but also faceC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be determined by comparing the loops that make up the face.

`Face.outerloop` will return the loop that bounds a face (excluding any internal edges).  `Face.loop` returns all of a face's loops including inner and outer.

So, by getting a list of all connected faces (using the example code with `all_connected` that you posted), you can iterate over those faces to determine if any of faceA's `outerloop` is shared by the iterated face.  If so, it is **not** an inset face, rather it is adjacent.

There is an alternative method posted here that might be a good way to go too: https://forums.sketchup.com/t/how-to-know-that-a-face-contains-another-face-using-ruby-api/21840/3

Note, in the linked post, they comment that you can't directly compare loops, but you can compare edges (which compose a loop).